# select events with and without likes in one query

Tags: mysql

I would like to SELECT all events and with them number of their likes. Likes are stored in a different table than events, since I need to know who gave a like to which event and when.

I know how to select events that have likes and merge rows together using GROUP BY. But I can't select events that have no likes together with events that have some likes.
Is there a way how to do it ?

This is the query I have:

```
SELECT e.*,count(p.id_plusone) as likes 
FROM plusone p,event e 
WHERE p.event_id = e.id_event 
GROUP BY e.id_event 
ORDER BY likes
```

The database structure looks like this:

```
event            plusone (like)
id_event         id_plusone
....             event_id
                 user_id
                 timestamp
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `outer join`:

```
SELECT e.*, count(p.id_plusone) as likes 
FROM event e
   LEFT JOIN plusone p ON p.event_id = e.id_event 
GROUP BY e.id_event 
ORDER BY likes
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Also in general I would try to avoid using commas in your `from` clause.

Comment: Shouldn't the left join be from event to plusone as OP wants to show all events irrespective of whether they have any corresponding likes or not?

Comment: @Harsh -- completely agree -- didn't look at it close enough. Thanks -- we both missed it :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a LEFT JOIN from event table to like table to get those  events which doesn't have any likes. Something like below:

```
SELECT e.*,count(p.id_plusone) as likes 
FROM event e left join plusone p on p.event_id = e.id_event 
GROUP BY e.id_event ORDER BY likes
```

Comment: Using `coalesce` with `count` will actually return the wrong value -- 1 instead of 0.  Here's a quick demonstration:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a009f/3

Comment: Agreed. Edited my answer.

Comment: You should use `coalesce(count(...), 0)` rather than `count(coalesce(..., 0))`

Comment: @Barmar -- I'm curious, why suggest using `coalesce` at all with `count`?   From my understanding, `count(null)` will return 0, so no need for `coalesce` (different than `sum` though): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/47497

Comment: @sgeddes Maybe not needed here. I often left join with a subquery that does the counts, and in that case I need to use `coalesce` in the outer query.

Comment: Or maybe I was thinking of `sum()`.

Comment: @Barmar -- fair enough, just making sure I wasn't missing something.  And Harsh, +1 for letting us spam comments under your post :)

Comment: @sgeddes, I am okay as long as it's relevant to the post contents ;-)